# How do i set up a core data model and with what relationships in this case?

Tags: core-data

I am trying to learn some Core Data, and i have limited knowledge in general when it comes to databases (which i know Core Data is not, it's an 'Object Graph Manager') so i am in somewhat deep need of some help to figuring out what exactly i need to store, and where. I have three entities that i would like to create in my model:

- `Team`
- `Player`
- `GameResult`

A team has the attribute `teamName` (string), but a team (in this case) should also have 4 players associated with it. This is where it already gets tricky for me to understand: How do i add/represent players (objects) as attributes within the `Team` entity?

The `Player` entity will for now only have an attribute of `name` as a string and preferably a unique ID(?) - to be able to keep track of individual results later on.

A `GameResult` however will have a few more attributes:

- homeTeam
- awayTeam
- homeTeamScore
- awayTeamScore
- dateForPlayedGame

Both homeTeam and awayTeam i imagine should be an instance of a entity type `Team` which i also do not understand how i could represent. I'm guessing i will need to set up a few relationships as well: a team can have many players (4 in my case) and a player can belong to many teams (not the homeTeam and awayTeam in the same game though).

I would really appreciate some thoughts and guidance on how this model could be set up.

Edit: I should probably have an Entity of `Game`. Should i have this instead of `GameResult`and let the gameResult be an attribute of `Game`or should i still have `GameResult`as an entity? What do you guys think? As i mentioned before: I have very limited knowledge about databases (in general)...as everyone can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > How do i add/represent players (objects) as attributes within the Team entity?

You want to have a "one to many" relationship between Team and Players.  Your model, when you create the one-may relationship, will automatically place an NSSet in your managed object that contains a list of players on the team.

> > The Player entity will for now only have an attribute of name as a string and preferably a unique ID(?) - to be able to keep track of individual results later on.

I know it sounds strange but don't worry about the unique ID.  Core Data will handle that for you and you'll never miss it.  You have to take this one on faith until you see it in action ;)

> > Both homeTeam and awayTeam i imagine should be an instance of a entity type Team which i also do not understand how i could represent.

I would probably think in terms of an attribute in the Team entity indicating "Home or Away".  But there are other options if you don't like that one.  I just think for for something that simple with only two possible values, this is probably the easy thing to do.  There is nothing to prevent using the same entity for both.

> > Edit: I should probably have an Entity of Game. Should i have this instead of GameResultand let the gameResult be an attribute of Gameor should i still have GameResultas an entity? What do you guys think? As i mentioned before: I have very limited knowledge about databases (in general)...as everyone can see.

Not sure what the difference would be. Seems to me like a Game entity that included whatever the attributes are for "Game result" would make sense.  A game always has a result and a result is always of a game.  So, I don't see why you'd need both.

I don't want to say you're better off without general database knowledge, but you are almost.  I had to forget just about everything I knew about SQL Server to be able to grasp Core Data.

The best thing I can say is that once "the light comes on" it will be simple and make perfect sense to you.  My biggest problem was in having to unlearn a lot of what I knew about relational databases coming in.

Main thing I can say is remember that everything is about the managed object.  You build your relationships into the model, and from then on you're dealing with NSSets of managed objects for the related entity.

Truthfully, it just makes too much sense to be easy to understand ;)

NOTE: One of the best things you can do is tinker with setting up the model, then generate your entity classes Editor | Create NSManaged Object Subclasses.  Then study those classes and understand each of the relationship sets in them.  That's what made things come clear to me, at least.

GLTY.

Comment: Thank you for this guidance. Just what i needed to be able to get started! :)

Comment: Feel free to post back if you hit problems. If I'm around I'll try to respond.